# How do I locate the .pid file in /var/lib/mysql when in terminal there is no such directory?

Tags: mysql, database, installation, root, pid

where do I go to open or find the /var/lib/mysql file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run for getting pid path.

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --print-defaults | tr " " "\n" | grep pid | tail -n 1
```

On debian result is --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

Comment: I ran that and there is no such file or directory.  I assume this is because I do not have the .pid file.  And without that, I cannot reset the mysql password or run it as root.  I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 4):

If it's the process id of the mysqld service you are needing to find, then you can do:

```
ps aux |grep [m]ysqld

# Result something like
root      2665  0.0  0.0   4644  1288 ?        S    Jul26   0:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld
  -------^^^^^^^--- that's the pid
```

Comment: What is every time pid is changing after running above command?

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Are you using `[m]ysqld` or just `mysqld`? If the latter, maybe you are seeing the pid of the `ps|grep` process and not that of the mysql server process.

Answer (score 1):

If the /var/lib/mysql directory does not exists, then the .pid in file in it can't exist.

Comment: You're correct because terminal once reported that the .pid file does not exist.  What do you suggest I do in order to get the mysql password reset and up and running? According to the mysql site, I would have to locate the .pid file first.  However, that's jsut not possible. @arnaud576875